# Being $X = [0,1] \cup [2,3) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and consider the metric space (X,d) with d being the inherited of $\mathbb{R}$ in X.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

- The Set A = [2,3) is closed or open
- {3} $\subset$ $\partial$A
- (X,d) is a complete metric space

Please, help me if im in the right way?

- $A$ will be an open set iff, $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists$$B_\epsilon(x)$, with $x$ $\in$ $A$; $B_\epsilon(x)\subset$ $A$. But when $\epsilon=1$ i can find a ball that contains points in $A$ ({2}) and in $X-A$ ({1}), so is not open. Then, it also is not a closed set because exists a limit point that is not in the set ({3})
- To {3} $\subset$ $\partial$A, a ball in center {3} with any radius will have point in the set and in its complement, what is false, because after the point {3} there's no more points in $X-A$.
- To be Complete, all cauchy sequences might have it limit points in the set, but i can find a cauchy sequence which its limit is not.
  $$x_n:=\{3-(\frac{1}{n});n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
  is a cauchy sequence and its limit is {3} which is not in the set.

Am i doing fine?

Comment: Your definition of open is not correct...

Comment: The definition of an open $U$ is that for each $x \in U$, *there exists $\epsilon \gt 0$* such that $B_\epsilon x \subset U$.

Comment: Well notice that $X$ is disconnected, so by definition it is the union of $2$ non-intersecting clopen sets. There is nothing to prove

Comment: Yeah! I just thought better and I noticed my mistake about open sets, thanks for the help. Now, the definition of 2-non-intersecting sets to be clopen is my true doubt. And about the definition of closed set, which says that all the limit point might be in the set?

Comment: @Lucas: When you look for limit points of $A$, you’re looking only for limit points **in the space** $X$. The point $3$ isn’t in $X$, so it’s completely irrelevant: it *can’t* be a limit point of $A$ in $X$, because it isn’t even in $X$. There are also a couple of ways to see that $A$ is closed in $X$ without looking at individual points. First, $A=[2,3]\cap X$, and $[2,3]$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, so $A$ is closed in $X$. Alternatively, $X\setminus A=[0,1]$, and $[0,1]$ is open in $X$ because it’s the intersection with $X$ of the open set $(-2,2)$ in $\Bbb R$.